# Importing date vector from Excel into R

Tags: r, excel

I'm reading an Excel spreadsheet into R, one of the columns contains dates in format

```
03-Jan-11
07-Feb-11
07-Mar-11
07-Mar-11
04-Apr-11
```

e.t.c

However when imported into R using read.xlsx2 they become numeric:

```
40546
40581
40609
40609
```

e.t.c.

How can I convert the numeric dates into their old format?

I have tried:

```
as.Date( dates, origin= "2011-01-03")
```

However this gave error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

and

```
as.Date(as.numeric(Directories$Insertion.Date),origin="2011/01/03")
```

Did not preserve the dates

Does anyone know how I can do this in R

Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, it is a factor column. Convert to numeric class. For example `as.Date(factor(40546), origin='2011-01-03')
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: In addition to akrun's comment, I think your interpretation of the origin parameter is incorrect - it's typically either `1970-01-01` or I think in Excel `1900-01-01` (number of days since ...). Take a look at `?as.Date`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end solved this with

```
 as.Date( as.numeric (as.character(Directories$Insertion.Date) ),origin="1899-12-30")
```

Thanks very much to the commenters for clearing up my confusion!